# Retrieve a Font Awesome or Bootstrap Icon (or React Component) from MongoDB into React

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building a database of hot sauce products in MongoDB Atlas for my React App. One attribute of the sauces is heat intensity. I'd like to use a bootstrap or font awesome icon to illustrate this. One flame, two flames, three flames...etc. I figured out a handful of ways to code it if I were storing the products statically in my React app, but since I want to have a dynamic inventory stock number attached to each product, I'm storing all the product descriptions in the database.

My question is how can I store the icon, in any of it's formats (bootstrap icon for example):

Unicode: U+F7F6

CSS: \F7F6

JS: \uF7F6

HTML: &#xF7F6

and then retrieve it.

Everything I've tried just errors or gives me a plain string in my div.

I'd also be all ears if you have a way to store and retrieve react components, as I can go the svg imported as a component route.

Like if I have

```
import { ReactComponent as Pep5 } from "../assets/pep5.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep4 } from "../assets/pep4.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep3 } from "../assets/pep3.svg";
```

and can somehow store and retrieve

```
<Pep4 className="heatScale"/>
```

My code for getting all the records in my db is:

```
recordRoutes.route("/sauce").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("products");
  db_connect
    .collection("sauces")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});

module.exports = recordRoutes;
```

All the other parts of my "product" are working great and coming across perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the boneheaded method I was trying to accomplish the svg version.

TL;DR I don't need to store the React Component code in the database, only an identifier I can later use to conditionally return the React Component I want from a function.

Imports:

```
import { ReactComponent as Pep5 } from "../assets/pep5.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep4 } from "../assets/pep4.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep3 } from "../assets/pep3.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep2 } from "../assets/pep2.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Pep1 } from "../assets/pep1.svg";
```

Function:

```
  function PepEval(heat) {
    const value = JSON.stringify(heat);
    console.log(value);
    if (value.includes("1")) {
      return <Pep1 className="peppers" />;
    } else if (value.includes("2")) {
      return <Pep2 className="peppers" />;
    } else if (value.includes("3")) {
      return <Pep3 className="peppers" />;
    } else if (value.includes("4")) {
      return <Pep4 className="peppers" />;
    } else if (value.includes("5")) {
      return <Pep5 className="peppers" />;
    }
    return "Something Broke";
  }
```

Div that calls the function:

```
        <div className="itemHeat">
          <PepEval value={{ heat }} />
        </div>
```

I'm sure JS has a Select Case type thing instead of all the else ifs but I wanted to get it working.

If someone has a better method for evaluating the JSON object that I'm bringing in, I'm all ears.